# Update mysql when cell value is edited in JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Well I have a JTable in my app that fetches records from a MySql database adn displays them in a sorted order.
Till now I have been using a separate JTextArea and a JComboBox to allow the users to edit the table, something like[image]

so whenever someone clicks on a row in the table the ID of the record is automatically updated below in a JLabel that lies before the JComboBox.

The question is how can I allow users to simply double click and edit values in the cells which would automatically fire a SQL Update query and update the same in the database. I want to allow this on certain Columns only not every Column.

A response with a code example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I allow users to simply double click and edit values in the cells which would automatically fire a SQL Update query and update the same in the database.

You can use a `TableModelListener` to be notified of changes to the `TableModel`.

> I want to allow this on certain Columns only not every Column.

The row/column is found in the `TableModelEvent` so you check the column that changed before invoking the SQL update.

One potential problem with this is that a TableModelEvent is generated even if the data isn't changed. That is if you place the cell in edit mode and, for instance, tab to the next cell without change the data and event will still be generated.

To get around this problem you may want to consider using the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). When using this class the event is only generated if the data has actually been changed.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do the same and get back to you if I have any further problems